# Roblox: Touched event returns incorrect position of projectile

Tags: lua, game-physics, collision, roblox, projectile

I've made a cannon in Roblox, it uses part velocity to launch cannon ball projectiles out the cannon. It attaches a function to the touched event for the cannon ball that's taken from server storage and moved to workspace. The cannon ball when touched and the part touched is not part of the cannon itself generates an explosion.

The problem is that it works for roughly 20 shots, its a different amount of successful cannon shots each time however after a few the cannon ball's position starts return incorrectly and as a result the explosions explode in mid air.

To figure out the root cause of this I've tried removing the explosion and making it spawn a part there instead and after roughly 20 shots it will start to make the parts appear in mid air instead of where the cannon ball actually collided. I've tried both making the cannon ball collide and non collide which made no difference. It appears that the position within the touched event function is not returning the true position of where the part was touched in 3D space.

```
    local function cannonMC1CTSEvent(player, mousePos)
    
        local cannonBall = game.ServerStorage.cannonball:Clone()
        cannonBall.Position = script.Parent.barrel.CFrame.Position
        cannonBall.Parent = workspace
    
        physicsService:SetPartCollisionGroup(cannonBall, "cannonBall")
    
        script.Parent.barrel.CFrame = CFrame.new(script.Parent.barrel.CFrame.Position, mousePos)
        cannonBall.CFrame = CFrame.new(script.Parent.barrel.CFrame.Position, mousePos)
        cannonBall.Velocity = cannonBall.CFrame.LookVector * 256
    
    
        local function generateExplosion()
            explosion = Instance.new("Explosion")
            explosion.BlastRadius = 2
            explosion.BlastPressure = 100
        
        end
    
        generateExplosion()
    
        cannonBall.Touched:Connect(function(touched)
            if touched.Parent.Name ~= "cannon" then
            
                explosion.Position = cannonBall.Position
                cannonBall:Destroy()
                explosion.Parent = workspace
            
                generateExplosion()
            
            end
        end)
```

Here is the code for the cannon ball, the code fires a cannon ball every time the user clicks which is done locally using a remote event to tell server to fire the cannon. I've been baffled with this issue and my first guess would be that it's just Roblox Part.Velocity being buggy. Thankyou in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if you have a correct code here - `generateExplosion` does nothing.

Comment: I used it to make sure there wasn't a delay when creating the explosion on the touched event. Pre generating most of the explosion just allowed me to remove that as a possibility for the cannonball giving me an incorrect position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent about 5 hours today trying to find the root of the issue. It's the Roblox touched event. It is inaccurate at detecting collision of moving parts. I figured out this was the issue by checking whether ArePartsTouchingOthers was true or false, the times the explosion was in mid air and inaccurate to the visual position of the cannonball when it collides was false whereas when it was correctly positioned it was true. Therefore I am going to remake my code around using ArePartsTouchingOthers instead of using the touched event.

Comment: Most Touched functions aren't the most accurate. I've worked on a cannon system and bow system in the past, in both I ended up having to utilize raycasting for more accurate systems. It wasn't that hard either, I just made the cannon ball non-collidable and had a loop that created a raycast using a former point and its current position.  Would recommend looking into that

Comment: Yeah I'll give that a look, I havn't worked with raycasting before but if it worked for you it might be worth a look. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

making an explosion before it touches something is a bad idea so try running the function when it collides. EDIT: you never gave the explosion a parent (but also don't pre-create the explosion) so try:

```
local function generateExplosion()
        explosion = Instance.new("Explosion",game.Workspace)
        explosion.BlastRadius = 2
        explosion.BlastPressure = 100
    
    end
```

Comment: This isn't the problem though. They said that creating a part shows that the position is incorrect. It's not a bad idea either (If I understand `Explosion`s correctly), he's trying to pre-create, but for whatever reason the function returns nothing.

Comment: You cannot pre create an explosion, when you make one you have to set the position immediately, Chances are that it works but they never tested it with print() and those kinds of stuff. EDIT: I JUST REALISED HE NEVER GAVE IT A PARENT

Comment: The reason I pre generated the explosion was to see if there was a delay with making the explosion on the touched event, I wasn't sure if the problem was that by the time the explosion was made, the position of the cannon ball was no longer the place of collision and that's why it was incorrectly displaying the explosion. I removed the generateExplosion function and moved the code back into the touched event, it makes no difference to the error I'm getting. Also I did give explosion a Parent its just in the touched event. Having the generate function worked fine before.

Comment: Also I want to remind you that the cannon works perfectly for around 20 shots, the explosions appear where the collisions happen however after a random amount (I checked to see if it was the same amount of shots every time, it wasn't) they start appearing 4 studs away or above the collision of the cannonball with the part it collides with. I've also tested it to make sure it wasn't colliding with something invisible by checking the color of the touched part to what I saw on screen.

Comment: So did the explosion spawn on the coords (0,0,0), somewhere else or does it not spawn entirely

Comment: No. I said that the explosion was appearing a couple of studs away from the collision point. I don't think you read and understood the my problem.